# Nested layouts in elm-mdl

Tags: elm, elm-mdl

I need to show 5 blocks that work independently in a page. I think that it is reasonable to nest 5 layouts into one top layout.
Is that approach reasonable or possible in elm-mdl package? I couldn't find any example or explanation about that case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the view of elm-mdl-dashboard](https://github.com/vipentti/elm-mdl-dashboard/blob/master/src/View.elm), you should use a Layout.render which take a Contents as parameter and return a `Html m`.

```
type alias Contents m =
    { header : List (Html m)
    , drawer : List (Html m)
    , tabs : ( List (Html m), List (Style m) )
    , main : List (Html m)
    }
```

What's good about it is that it takes a `List (Html m)` as main, so you can redefine Layouts inside main safely! :)

I think you should take inspiration from [elm-mdl-dashboard](https://github.com/vipentti/elm-mdl-dashboard) in general.